# Can topological groups be smoothed into lie groups?

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups

I've been thinking about this for the past couple of days and I'm really not sure of the answer..
By "smoothed" I mean that for any arbitrary precision we can find a Lie group which approximates the topological group within the precision, much in the same way we can find an arbitrary smooth approximation of a topological manifold.
I'm no expert in the theory of Lie groups however so I'm not sure if this idea can be extended.
Does anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "find a Lie group which approximates the topological group within the precision," or what you mean by "find an arbitrary smooth approximation of a topological manifold." Can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you cite something for the smooth approximations of topological manifolds? (I am not really familiar enough with this subject to know what you're referring to.) And what would it mean exactly for a Lie group to approximate a topological group to within a given precision?

Comment: Well, you can embed a topological n-manifold in R^7n+1 (I think you can actually do it in R^2n+1 but don't quote me on it). Once you've done that, you can approximate this surface to arbitrary precision by the wierstrass theorem. For a Lie group to appoximate a topological group I'd mean something like this, embedding the topological group somewhere or show that it's representations can be matched by a lie groups representation within some neighbourhood. Although I'd be open to accept better definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question seems to be a version of Hilbert's fifth problem. There are some obvious necessary conditions for a topological group to be a Lie group: it should be locally compact Hausdorff. Somewhat more subtly, there should be a neighborhood of the identity that does not contain any non-trivial subgroup. It is a famous theorem usually attributed to (at least!) Gleason, Montgomery-Zippin, and Yamabe that the converse of this statement is also true: a locally compact Hausdorff topological group such that there is a neighborhood of the identity not containing a non-trivial subgroup is a Lie group. I like Terry Tao's book

http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=gsm-153

as a reference for and introduction to this topic.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds good! I'll see if I can pick up a copy from somewhere. Could you offer any other references? I usually like to learn from a few different places at once.

Comment: @GenericUsrnme Sure, there's also Kaplansky's book "Lie algebras and locally compact groups" (University of Chicago Press).